# Swift: Multiple detailTextLabel lines in a UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableViewCell

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

that has the following setup:

```
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15.0)
    cell.textLabel?.text = titleString

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = descriptionString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

descriptionString consists of an HTML string.

I've set

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

However this results in a messy tableview display when detailTextLabel is greater than 1 line. The detailTextLabel wraps onto a the next tableview cell.

What is the solution for this? UITableViewAutomaticDimension does not appear to be working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

#### Multiline Label in table view Cell

Define first

```
private let useAutosizingCells = true

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if useAutosizingCells && tableView.respondsToSelector(Selector("layoutMargins")) {
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
}
```

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)     


        if useAutosizingCells && tableView.respondsToSelector(Selector("layoutMargins")) {
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: It seems the only difference here is setting tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88 and  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension in the viewDidLoad() method. Unfortunately this still does not work. Note also in your example you're not using a UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle        .